# Expression or Algorithm to get number of matrices with odd number occurrences of specific value in each row and column

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have to find total number of matrices that could be formed satisfying given condition.

Conditions -

- Each matrix is filled with only 2 elements : (x) and (-x) where x is any
  integer. [x is received from our web-app]
- Now, such filled matrix is valid only if (-x) appears odd number of times in
  each row and at the same time in each column.

Example -

1. Matrix (2x1) - valid matrices = 0

> ```
>  x 
> -x
> ```

2. Matrix (2x2) - valid matrices = 2

> ```
> -x  x      x -x
>  x -x     -x  x
> ```

3. Matrix (3x3) - valid matrices = 22

> ```
> 6 combinations when -x appears once per row as well as once per column 
> 3 combinations when -x appears trice per row but once per column
> 9 combinations when -x appears trice for 1 row and trice for 1 column (shape L,T,+ mirror images)
> 3 combinations when -x appears trice per column but once per row 
> 1 combinations when -x appears at all positions
> ```

How should I calculate number of matrices satisfying given conditions - is there any algorithm or formula present for such cases?

Comment: For the `3x3` case, using another method, I got 16 combinations. Are you sure of your result ?

Comment: @Damien I am not sure of my result. I could figure only 13 matrices satisfying my condition. Please let me know how more combinations can be formed ? I am trying to derive factorial based expression but not yet came to conclusion.

Comment: For Matrix (3x3) - valid matrices = 13, how do you get it? just by trying different combinations? or there is any formula?

Comment: @ManojBanik I got it just by trying different combinations on paper. No formula derived yet - thats the question.

Comment: I got 13 as well, I don't know how @Damien got 16. You may consider to include all 13 cases in pictures/matrix form.

Comment: @ManojBanik i explained how I got 16 in my answer. What is missing in the 13 are e.g. the cases when you have one row with 1 -x and others with 3.

Comment: @Damien Please include that matrix here at a comment.

Comment: @ManojBanik For example `+ + - // - - - // + + -`

Comment: @Damien, does it not violate the second rule -  Matrix in which (-x) appears odd number of times in each row and at the same time in each columns are valid.? They are both odd though. I just want to make sure with PriyankaW. Thanks.

Comment: @ManojBanik, thank you for attention. Now with Damien's idea I am able to form 22 combinations now. Please check update in question. So, I can not use Damien's formula.

Comment: ` trice per row but once per column` ??? I tried to find a solution with this constraint, I could not find it. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Damien its automatically once per column when trice per row comes. (Examples - 1)3 negative in 1st row other elements are +ve, 2)3 -ve in 2nd row, 3)3 -ve in 3rd row).. simillarly trice per column but once per row would be - 1)3 negative in 1st column, 2)3 negative in second column, 3)3 negative in third column

Comment: @PriyankaW "3 negative in 1st row other elements are +ve": the parity is not respected in second and third rows. Or maybe I completely misunderstood the problem

Comment: @Damien Condition is in valid matrix, +ve and -ve values should be arranged such that each row and each column must have only odd number of -ve integers. Seems my question is misleading, please check edited version. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call n the number of rows and m the number of columns.

You get (n-1)(m-1) degrees of freedom, corresponding to the upper (n-1)(m-1) submatrix.

Then you have to calculate the last row and the last column, in such a way that the conditions are fulfilled.

You have a potential issue when calculating the last `[n][m]` value. If n and m have a different parity, no solution is possible.

Elsewhere, you get 2^{(n-1)(m-1)} combinations.

**Edit**

Please note that the parity constraints on rows and columns correspond to linear equations in Z/2Z. Therefore, the set of solutions in a vector space in Z/2Z, the size of which is 2^{something} or 0.

Comment: @vonbrand Thank you for trying to improve my answer, but please note that unfortunately SO doesnt not accept latex formulas !